# Cannot push to git: url cannot be parsed

Tags: git, azure, devops

input:

`git push`

output:

```
warning: url has no scheme: github.com
fatal: credential url cannot be parsed: github.com
```

I am trying to push to azure devops, (at the same time I need the opportunity to push to github once in a while)

Running: Ubuntu on WSL2

I dont have a list of all the things I have tried in my head, but I it does include config on git credentials and setting http-somthing to `true` to accomondate a url per project.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:
My .gitconfig file looks like this

```
[credential "github.com"]
        useHttpPath = true
```

and my .git-credentials file looks like this:

```
https://<user>:<token>@github.com
https://<user>:<token>@dev.azure.com
```

Perhaps this can help.
PS. I have very limited knowledge about git unfortunately and am rather frustrated of this "helper-tool" getting in my way all the time. Is there any other tooling for version control that does not completely fall trough on usability and adoption?

Comment: What is the url set for that remote?

Comment: This is what i got running command in project folder,  @eftshift0

> git remote -v
origin  https://<org>@dev.azure.com/<org>/<project_name>/_git/<repo_name> (fetch)
origin  https://<org>@dev.azure.com/<org>/<project_name>/_git/<repo_name> (push)

Answer (score 0):

From Azure "[Get started with Git from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-cmdline?view=azure-devops)", make sure your URL is:

```sh
cd /path/to/local/repo
git remote set-url origin https://dev.azure.com/<organization>/<Project>/_git/<RepoName>
```

Then try again.

Comment: "<user>/<Project>"? isn't it "<organization>/<Project>"

Comment: @cltj Yes, I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @cltj What `git config credential.helper` does return when executed in WSL2 session in the root folder of the repository?